# Simulating state change with enzyme and React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new on unit tests with React and I am struggling to understand what's happening here.
I started testing a Login component, which contains two inputs.

```
<Form className="login" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
    <Segment>
        <Form.Input id="username" name="username" value={username} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Form.Input id="password" name="password" value={password} type="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Button color="orange" disabled={loading} size="large">
          Submit
        </Button>
    </Segment>
</Form>

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateFromProps, { setUser })(Login));
```

and on my Login-test.js file, I tried two different approaches that didn't work.

```
describe('username input', () => {
   it('should respond to change event and change the state of the login container', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
      wrapper.find('#username').first().value = 'fakeusername';
      expect(wrapper.state('username').toEqual('fakeusername'));
   });
});
```

and

```
describe('password input', () => {
    it('should respond to change event and chante state of the login container', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Login />);
      expect(wrapper.find('#password').simulate('change', { target: { name: 'password', value: 'fakepassword' } }));
      expect(wrapper.state('password')).toEqual('fakepassword');
    });
});
```

The errors I am receiving are:

> ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components
>
> Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

respectively

How can I simulate it properly?

"jest": "23.6.0",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0"

Comment: Can you show full `Login` component?

Comment: @Alex sure, I edited my question with the login component markup.

Comment: it's still not clear if `Login` is class component

Comment: perhaps will work with `mount` instead of `shallow`

Comment: @Alex it is. Anyway, it seems to not work with HOC. So I had to restructure a little bit and split this file into two.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself the headache and import the Login component directly.

i.e.

```
export class Login class....
```

and then

```
import { Login } from './Login'
```